# why is this recursion not working to eliminate all spaces before the first word in a string

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am trying to make a function to delete all the unwanted space before the very first word in a string:

```
def spacefirst(sentence):
   for t in range(len(sentence)):
      if t == 0 and sentence[t] == ' ':
          sentence = sentence[t+1 :]
      else:
          sentence = ''.join(sentence) 
          return sentence
      spacefirst(sentence)
```

Why that recursion is not working?

Comment: Please add input and the desired output for better understanding.

Comment: You aren't returning the newly trimmed value. `sentence` is not modified in place, because `str` values are immutable.